# Cypress test stops to execute in the middle of code

Tags: cypress

Here is my code:

```
context('Actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('http://www.staging.365dropship.com') 
        cy.contains('Login').click()
        cy.wait(10000)
          .get('#fancybox-frame').then(($iframe) => {
                const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
                cy.wrap($body).find('#login-username').type('testtust100@gmail.com')
                cy.wrap($body).find('#login-password').type('1234567')
                cy.wrap($body).find('button').click()
            })     
    })

    it('continue', () => {
        cy.wait(10000)
        cy.url().should('include', '/owner/index')
        cy.get('a.icon-sale').click()
        cy.wait(10000)
    })

})
```

On the first wait after login test stops execution with no reason and no errors in logs... Can somebody help me where I make a mistake?

[that is the last screen I caught before test stops, the wait is not complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyPtO.png)

[after I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvfjW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned test works fine at my place. I guess the credentials are known invalid, but it fails at the point where I expected it to fail:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. J. I use differenet credentials and its ok. Just after click button to login next wait doesn't finish and it not try to assert. Test stops on the middle of wait and I get screen that there's no test to run...

Comment: Can you add something like a screenshot or a screencast? At this moment the information is just not enough to run on.

Comment: The above test works for me as well, it now failing due to invalid credentials.

Comment: For me it run with invalid credentials as well. I think problem start when it switching from frame to original window. I don't know how to paste screencast here... I can send it or you can run code with this credentials  login 'testtust100@gmail.com'   pass '1234567'

Comment: It is indeed the change from Iframe to the original window. With valid credentials I have the same problem. I have no experience at all with Iframes, especially not with the combination of Iframes and no-Iframes. But please add this information to the original post and title since it is crucial to reproduce your problem.